# How do I set errno from Go

Tags: go, cgo

I have a C function calling a Go routine via cgo.  I need to Go routine to set the errno correctly so the C thread can inspect it's errno and act accordingly.  Unable to google on how to set the errno via Go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, you can still set it via C-function that you call via cgo.

```
package main

// #include <errno.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
//
// void setErrno(int err) {
//      errno = err;
// }
//
import "C"

func main() {
        C.setErrno(C.EACCES)
        C.perror(C.CString("error detected"))
        C.setErrno(C.EDOM)
        C.perror(C.CString("error detected"))
        C.setErrno(C.ERANGE)
        C.perror(C.CString("error detected"))
}
```

On my system it outputs

```
error detected: Permission denied
error detected: Numerical argument out of domain
error detected: Numerical result out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer directly to errno from go, see [cgo doesn't like errno on Linux](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/1360). From that thread:

> I don't know what's wrong, but it doesn't matter since that's not a
>   safe use of errno anyway.  Every call into  C might happen in a
>   different OS thread, which means that referring to errno directly is
>   not guaranteed to get the value you want.

As of [3880041](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/pOmTeW_hZ8M) attempts to refer to `C.errno` will elicit an error message:

```
cannot refer to errno directly; see documentation
```

---

As [pointed out in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38358903/714501), setting it from a C function works.